# JDBC connection to mongodb running on Meteor server on Cloud 9

Tags: mongodb, meteor, remote-access, cloud9-ide, db-schema

I have a Meteor app running on Cloud 9 and I would like to connect to MongoDB from a window app that I am in trial period (DBSCHEMA: http://www.dbschema.com/).

Cloud 9 guys told me that I need my DB to listen to `0.0.0.0:8082`.

In cloud9 I started my app using command: `$ meteor --port $IP:$PORT`.
I also created a db and user that has role "userAdmin" to this database.

In another terminal, at c9, "Meteor mongo" command give me connecting to: `127.0.0.1:8081/meteor`

In DBSchema ping to the server is succesfull, but connection is refused.
So, I am trying to change to 0.0.0.0:8082 but I cant figure out how and not sure its going to work.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use environment variable MONGO_URL=your-mongo-server-ip-or-hostname:8082 in meteor and start mongo with port 8082 on 0.0.0.0 with the config file

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

Ideally, you should not expose you dB to the outside (so not bind to 0.0.0.0 which exposes the DB on all interfaces including the public IP).

If you want to access it with Robomongo, bind to localhost, and then you should create a ssh tunnel to the server from you local terminal with the command

`ssh -L 8082:localhost:8082 your-host`

then connect to it with robomongo at localhost:8082 –

Comment: I started meteor with: `MONGO_URL=mongodb://0.0.0.0:8082 meteor --port $IP:$PORT` and then started mongo with config file `mongod --bind_ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8082 --dbpath=data --nojournal` but I got this error `Unclean shutdown detected.
Please visit http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for recovery instructions.`. Am I missing something?

Comment: you should start mongo first, which Meteor depends on. then start meteor.
Meteor should not start a mongo instance if the MONGO_URL is passed, but it will complain if mongo is not there. BTW, using 0.0.0.0 binds to all interfaces. If you're on the same host use 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'

Comment: I am trying to connect from anywhere, to a mongodb hosted inside cloud9. Could you please give me the comands to: 1) Start mongodb (with 0.0.0.0:8082 right?) and 2) Run meteor with MONGO_URL (so meteor should not start a new instance?). I have been trying to do this longer than a week, so your help is very welcome. Thanks

Comment: I have "MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/meteor"  <--- this is the name of the db you use, for meteor it defaults to meteor, but you can name it anything. 
Then I actually start mongo with the defaults. 
What kind of errors are you having? Did you check how to resolve your above error on mongo? It may well be that you crashed you db and it's not starting right, but that has nothing to do with Meteor, so first try to start mongo and see if you can access your data with the mongo shell.

Comment: sorry, I totally missed the obviosu... 'mongo' in my string is the hostname of my server. I had given 0.0.0.0 as example above but that's not a valid IP for a server, from the client point of view!    I guess this is you problem: you need to give your MONGO_URL the IP of the server that is running mongodb! so not 0.0.0.0:8082 but mongodb://<your-server-ip>:8082/meteor. I updated the answer

Comment: dont worry, but I am still confused. Look: 1) I create a meteor project on cloud9, 2) I opened a terminal and started mongo with `mongod --port=8082`, 3) I opened another terminal and started the app with `MONGO_URL=mongodb://<my-project>.<my-user>.c9.io:8082/meteor meteor --port $IP:$PORT` (<my-project>.<my-user>.c9.io is the host url). The app is running and looks fine, but I cant connect to mongo from a windows client in my notebook (I am using DBSchema and Robomongo to test it). My goal is to work with my hosted db with ER tools, maybe another solution is possible.

Comment: You should not expose you dB to the outside. If you want to access it you should create a ssh tunnel to the server from you local terminal with SSL -L 8082:localhost:8082 your-host.  And then connect to it with robomongo at localhost:8082

Comment: Well, in cloud 9 you are not able to create a ssh tunnel to your hosted workspace. I am trying now with a Digital Ocean droplet, connect from cloud 9 with ssh key (already done) but now I am figuring out how to connect from my PC, running windows. How (where) can I run this command? `SSL -L 8082:localhost:8082 your-host`

Comment: run in the terminal.
If you can't SSH to your server, how do you run your commands there?

Comment: if you need a mongo UI, you migt also want to look at mongo-express , a nodejs UI for mongo that can run on your server, but you'd need to have a proxy and authentication so it's not open to anyone

Comment: Finally I managed to configure a SSH tunnel to a Digital Ocean server and access the db from Robomongo in my local PC. DBSchema seems to have same issue with the jdbc driver, because I couldn't connect using this software. Now I am seeing at mongovue and mongochef to see the best tool. Thanks a lot for the help.